# fontspec: Changing number style also affects letters

Tags: fontspec

I would like to have Small Caps font with Lining numbers. For this I set `SmallCapsFeatures = { Numbers = Lining }`. However, with this, the letters are no longer Small Caps. Is there any way to set the numbers' style without affecting the letters?

[image]

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{SourceSansPro-Regular.otf}
    [
      Scale          = MatchLowercase ,
      BoldFont       = SourceSansPro-Bold.otf ,
      ItalicFont     = SourceSansPro-RegularIt.otf ,
      BoldItalicFont = SourceSansPro-BoldIt.otf ,
      SmallCapsFeatures = { Numbers = Lining } ,
      BoldFeatures   = {
        SmallCapsFeatures = { Numbers = Lining } ,
      }
    ]


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

{\scshape A0b1c2d3}

{\bfseries\scshape A0b1c2d3}

{\bfseries A0b1c2d3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `SmallCapsFeatures = { Letters = SmallCaps, Numbers = Lining}`. I seem to recall it working for me.

Comment: @Ingmar With this the numbers are not `Lining`. Actually in this case the `Numbers` key seems to be useless.

Comment: Why do you include `\ExplSyntaxOn`? At any rate, the example works if you delete `SmallCapsFont     = * ,` and `SmallCapsFont     = SourceSansPro-Bold.otf,`.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you for pointing this out. Earlier when I didn't realize `SmallCapsFeatures` can be set also inside `BoldFeatures`, the font behaves wrongly so I added them explicitly. The `\ExplSyntaxOn` is because the commands are copied from my document class file and may contain extra spaces.

Comment: Does the image still match the output of your edited MWE? I get small cap letters and also small cap numbers, which are desirable and not found in many fonts.

Comment: Since lining figures are the default in this font family, there’s no reason to specify them unless you’re trying to undo an earlier call for old-style figures.

Comment: @Thérèse Yes, it still matches. Unfortunately for me it doesn't look like a good feature, as I am using `\scshape` in the titles, and the numbers in `\contentslabel` looks a little bit inconsistent comparing with those titles in normal font shape.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the fonts? https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans

Comment: @Thérèse I'm using the one contained in TeX Live 2021. Is there any important difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short Answer

```
SmallCapsFeatures = { Numbers=Lining, Letters=SmallCaps }
```

#### Longer Answer

By default, `SmallCapsFeatures` activates `Letters=SmallCaps` (the `smcp` faature).  Setting `SmallCapsFeatures=`manually, overrode that.  You want to enable both.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{SourceSansPro-Regular.otf}
    [
      Scale          = MatchLowercase ,
      BoldFont       = SourceSansPro-Bold.otf ,
      ItalicFont     = SourceSansPro-RegularIt.otf ,
      BoldItalicFont = SourceSansPro-BoldIt.otf ,
      SmallCapsFeatures = { Numbers = Lining, Letters=SmallCaps } ,
      BoldFeatures   = {
        SmallCapsFeatures = { Numbers = Lining, Letters=SmallCaps } ,
      }
    ]


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

{\scshape A0b1c2d3}

{\bfseries\scshape A0b1c2d3}

{\bfseries A0b1c2d3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example works for me and produces SmallCaps and lining numbers. As Thérèse said they are used by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{SourceSans3-Regular.otf}
[     Scale          = MatchLowercase ,
      BoldFont       = SourceSans3-Bold.otf ,
      ItalicFont     = SourceSans3-It.otf ,
      BoldItalicFont = SourceSans3-BoldIt.otf ,
]

\begin{document}

\sffamily

{\noindent\scshape Regular SmallCaps \quad A0b1c2d3 } \newline
{\bfseries\scshape Bold SmallCaps \quad A0b1c2d3}\newline
{\bfseries Bold No Caps \quad A0b1c2d3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I might have misstated the question. Actually by `Lining`, what in my mind were normal numbers like those in the third line, not the small caps ones :(

Comment: @Jinwen Using full-sized numbers with small caps is regrettable, and the designers of this typeface are trying to prevent it. To judge by your comment above, your real question is probably how to use small caps in titles without affecting `\contentslabel` too, but your MWE doesn't allow me to guess further at your real use case.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you for this. I finally realize that this is actually a nice feature of the font, and I have processed `\contentslabel` separately to protect it from `\scshape`. Now everything is fine.